# Create a Java object only if needed?

Tags: java, object, ram

To save RAM I want to create classes just if they are needed and later be reused.

My class is this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Engine implements ActionListener {

    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    Boolean addWindow = false;

    Engine(){}

    //@ void actionPerformed()
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){

        if ( evt.getActionCommand().equals("add") ) {
            if ( addWindow = false ) {
                Add Add = new Add();
                Add.setVisible(true);
            }
            else Add.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

(Just one class of a project)

I think it's just a stupid error by myself but I can't figure it out.

But if I try to compile it says:

> Engine.java:21: error: non-static method setVisible(boolean) cannot be
>   referenced from a static context: else Add.setVisible(true); (Marker
>   is at the point between Add and setVisible().)

I don't want to recreate the Add class everytime. Just reuse if it already was created.

Comment: if ( addWindow = false ) { should be == probably...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Add add = new Add();
if ( addWindow == false ) { //Thanks to @TofuBeer's comment. I didn't notice this at all.         
    add.setVisible(true);
}
else
    add.setVisible(true);
```

Since you're using the `Add`(which is the name of the Class itself), it is trying to invoke the method, statically, which is throwing the error as its not a static method in your class `Add`.

Use the instance you've created to call the method and make sure, the instance name isn't exactly the class name(class name is with capital `A`).

**Add** - class name

**add** - instance name (if you give `Add` here also, it'll consider the class name instead of the instance name).

Comment: Will only partially work since `add` will be scoped to the `if` block, and not available in the `else`.

Comment: are you sure its exactly the same? Java is `CASE-SENSITIVE`. Keep that in mind.

Comment: It makes sense but would create the Add class even it will never be used :(

Comment: You're gonna set the visibility to either `true` or `false`. Hence, you'll need it in either case.

Comment: Is there NO WAY to create a class just if it's needed? This would save a lot of performance in bigger projects!

Comment: Are you going to use the `add` instance anywhere else in your code? And yes, you can do that, but in your case, its required for both if and else, thought `setVisibility` to `true` in both cases, makes no sense at all.